# Mysql : multiple tables or one big table?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, innodb

This question has been already asked but I've not found a "1 voice answer".

Is it better to do :

- 1 big table with :

user_id | attribute_1 | attribute_2 | attribute_3 | attribute_4

- or 4 smal tables with :
  user_id | attribute_1

user_id | attribute_2

user_id | attribute_3

user_id | attribute_4

1 big table or many small tables ? Each user can only have 1 value for attribute_X. We have a lot of data to save (100 millions users). We are using innoDB. Performance are really important for us (10 000 queries / s).

Thanks !

François

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the data, but from your description, neither is the most optimal. Instead, you can have a table that has: user_id, attribute_num, attribute -- so since each user has just one value for attribute_X, this covers everything in just 3 fields that can be indexed. For some specific tasks this might not be the best option though so again, depends on what you want.

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself is, do you usually need to get more than 1 attribute for the same user in the same query? If you are getting multiple and they are in different tables then the performance will be slower due to the table joins required.

Comment: @sn00k4h We generally made only atomic select / update (one attribute at the time for caching reasons). So, for asking 10 attributes, we made 10 call (but maybe only 1 or 0 request, depending of the cache state).

Comment: @Ynhockey we can't use "user_id, attribute_num, attribute" because the attribute field can be an int, bigint, date, float, etc...

Comment: By the way, the 2nd solution is called [Vertical Partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(database)) and has some positive effects on search efficiency (narrower tables, less indexes). But queries generally require more joins (not that this is bad, DBMS are really good at joining tables).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I think we'll go on this way

Comment: Trying to optimise the cache hit in the way you mentioned may or may not actually improve your performance depending on various factors. If I were you I would just try the different possible designs and compare the performance because that's the only way you know for (more) certain. Same design for different set of data can perform very differently. Also another possible design you can try is a hybrid of both ways - put the 'attributes' with data types that are relatively small (e.g.: int, date) in the same table and separate out those that are larger.

Answer (score 1):

If you adhere to the **Zero, One or Many** principle, whereby there is either no such thing, one of them, or an unlimited number, you would always build properly normalized tables to track things like this.

For instance, a possible schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user_attributes (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  attribute_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  attribute_value VARCHAR(255),
  UNIQUE INDEX index_user_attributes_name(user_id, attribute_name)
);
```

This is the basic key-value store pattern where you can have *many* attributes per user.

Although the storage requirements for this is higher than a fixed-columns arrangement with the perpetually frustrating names like `attribute1`, the cost is small enough in the age of terabyte-sized hard-drives that it's rarely an issue.

Generally you'd create a single table for this data until insertion time becomes a problem. So long as your inserts are fast, I wouldn't worry about it. At that point you would want to consider a *sharding* strategy to divide this data into multiple tables with an identical schema, but only if it's required.

I would imagine that would be at the ~10-50 million rows stage, but could be higher if the amount of insert activity in this table is relatively low.

Don't forget that the best way to optimize for read activity is to use a cache: The fastest database query is the one you don't make. For that sort of thing you usually employ something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to store the results of previous fetches, and you would invalidate this on a write.

As always, benchmark any proposed schema at *production* scale.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer. The problem is that we made request on the attribute value (sorting, filtering, etc...), and each attribute can be different (date, int, bigint, float). So we can't use Varchar for storing the attribute data.

Comment: If you have a fixed schema, then create columns with the appropriate types, one record per user. Your example with `attribute1` and so forth is typical of some apps where that's literally what the column is called. What you're doing sounds like it will melt down unless you layer on some kind of search engine on top like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) to take some of the strain off of your server. MySQL needs indexes to be performant, but large, complicated indexes can slow insertion times.

Comment: A variation on this key-value approach is to have several value tables, one for each type, where you will need to select from all of them and combine them together. Indexes would be set for a specific `attribute_name` or `attribute_name` and `user_id` combination.

Comment: If you're really trying to stretch this, you'd probably need some kind of map-reduce layer to fan out your queries across N database instances, though. If you're doing that, you want your tables to be as simple and generic as practical. Remember it's quite difficult to remove columns from large tables, but easier to drop tables that represent a column. I'm not sure exactly how you'd go about this for your particular case, as it's not clear if you're talking about hypothetical or actual users.

Comment: We are talking about actual users and we know the very hard problem to add column to a big database, that's why we are thinking to change to very small tables but we don't really kno if it's a good idea or not

Comment: If you're actually dealing with >100 million records, all options are on the table. You might want to try making a schema with a table *per* attribute, as you hinted at, and see how that works in practice. Dropping or adding attributes would involve dropping or adding tables. Messy to maintain but often effective.

Comment: Thanks Tadman, we'll try this solution tomorrow. As we have atomic getter and setter, I think this solution will be easy to implement.

Comment: this approach means that reading data would involve multiple joins, it's not only question about storage... how about read performance?

Comment: @Prokurors If the table gets to be so large that reads are crippling, consider sharding it by attribute or by entity (in this case `user_id`). Normally you can maintain a balance here between performance and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

1 big table with :
user_id | attribute_1 | attribute_2 | attribute_3 | attribute_4

will make your management easier.  Too many individual lookups otherwise, which will also complicate programming against the DB with the chance to increase application errors.